# Java: Store start and end time point

Tags: java, date

Is there a convenient way to store time points (like a start and end time point)?

I need to store responsibilities where every timespan an userId is assigned.
I thought of:

```
HashMap<Date[], Integer> responsibilities;
```

Where the Date-array stores the start- and end-date, but is there a more convenient way?

Comment: What all have you tried so far?

Comment: More convenient to drop the oldfashioned `Date` class and use the modern ones. Maybe `java.time.Instant`.

Comment: Arrays don’t have proper `hashCode` methods, so don’t use them as keys in a `HashMap`. At least wrap them in a class with `equals` and `hashCode`. But then you may just as well take the step to [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44259767/5772882).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
org.threeten.extra.Interval.of( start , end )
```

## `Interval`

The [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project contains a pair of `java.time.Instant` objects.

The `Interval` class has several methods you may find helpful such as contains, overlaps, abuts, intersection, union, and span.

The `Interval` class is defined as Half-Open, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a noon lunch break interval might start at 12:00:00 (noon) and run up to, but not include, 13:00:00 (1 PM). This approach is wise and practical, and is common in date-time handling.

The `Instant` class is built into Java 8 and later. It stores a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;
Instant end = start.plusHours( 2 );
Interval interval = Interval.of( start , end );
```

Extract either instant by calling `getStart` and `getEnd`.

To see the `Instant` object through the lens of a particular region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), apply a time zone. The resulting [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) is the very same simultaneous moment on the timeline but with a wall-clock time some number of hours and minutes ahead or behind [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  // A few hours behind UTC.
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

## `Map`

Create your [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) using the `Interval` as the key.

```
Map< Interval , User > map = new HashMap<>() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

create a class

```
class TimePane {

    private long start;
    private long end;

    .... 
    //setters, getters, equals, hashcode

}
```

and use the map

```
Map<TimePane, Integer> p = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: constructor, `toString()`, … BTW, for the `toString()` it oculd still be convenient to use `Instant` rather than `long`, maybe even `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: maybe OP need to update the question and suggest java8 APIs

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ you should highlight the `equals` and `hashCode` needs to be overriden, otherwise the suggestion is all right

Comment: @BalazsVago i placed in the comment as: '***//setters, getters, equals, hashcode***

Comment: Such a class already exists: [`org.threeten.extra.Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html)